# Non GPS GeoLocation API - Google Vs. others (Skyhook / Navizon / Xtify / etc)

Tags: java, iphone, android, geolocation, location

I am working on creating an LBS location aware app for iPhone, Android, Java, and Blackberry, which does **NOT** rely on GPS.

I therefore need a GSM cell tower GeoLocation API to identify the phone's location. I can use 3rd party solutions such as Google's Geolocation API / Skyhook / Navizon / Xtify / etc.

From what I understand, Google's Geolocation API is free, while all the others are not free and do not have as much coverage as Google's.

Therefore the obvious solutions would be to write my mobile application using and accessing Google's Geolocation API.

The dilemma seems too simple and if it is too good to be true, it usually is.

What am I missing...??

Many thanx

Comment: I believe that while Google's is free, it's limited. You can only make a few thousand calls to it per day. If you have a high traffic service, plan accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

I definitely agree with Joculls advice - that you should estimate your hourly, daily, monthly throughput to verify whether the APIs will support this throughput for your app or service.

I would also remark that it is likely that Skyhook has as good (or much better) positioning capabilities than either Google or Apple.  They have been tracking WiFi APN's for many years now, so I would imagine their database is quite accurate (note that both Google and Apple originally utilized Skyhook if memory serves me correctly).

Another couple of points to consider, is other sources of geo-location that do not rely strictly on WiFi APN's, and may be available from corresponding APIs within the host mobile device platform.  Celltower triangulation (e.g. using Observed Time Difference of Arrival - or OTDOA) is another technique for semi-accurate location fixes.  These type of services may be available from the host mobile device API (with all the calculations handled by the API itself).  Alternatively, they may provide you with the core API methods to interrogate Celltower's and other metadata (e.g. the Mobile Country Code, etc.).

Hope this helps!
BR/Brian.

Comment: Thanx gto406. indeed I am more into GSM location, rather than Wifi location calculation